# How to get the item inside dd?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to get the things inside dd only.
I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/'
pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

for a in soup.select('div.coLeft.cate.mBottom a[href]'):
    print "http://www.brothersoft.com"+ a['href']
```

But the output give all inside the class. I only need the item inside dd only. How to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `dd` inbetween:

```
for a in soup.select('div.coLeft.cate.mBottom dd a[href]'):
    #                                         ^^
    print "http://www.brothersoft.com"+ a['href']
```